# When 'while looping' a mysql $row result it only works in the first instance

Tags: php, mysql, loops

Can anyone help - this is driving me mad.

I am calling a mysql table and wish to display the results (or check the results with an if statement) more than once. But in this loop (see below) it only calls the table and its rows as an array in the first instance (of $i=1). This code will build 20 divs called Box but only populate the first one with table data. Why?

I think that I should be using a foreach loop within the outer loop (I have got this to work in wordPress with that btw) but can't figure out the syntax. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
$i=1;
while ($i <= 20)
{
    echo "<div class=\"Box ".$i."\">";
    echo $i;
    echo "<br>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo $row['name'];
    }
    echo "</div>";
    $i++;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand, you are attempting to use the same result resource multiple times in a loop.

After looping over the result resource the first time, you need to rewind it back to its original position to be able to loop over it again.  It can be rewound with `mysql_data_seek($result, 0)`, but a better strategy is to load the whole thing into an array before your loops and then iterate the array in each loop:

```
// Load everything into the array `$results` first.
$results = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $results[] = $row['name'];
}

// Better an incremental for loop than a while with a counter
// for a situation where you know the endpoint values of $i
for ($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++)
{
    echo "<div class='Box $i'>";
    echo $i;
    echo "<br>";
    // Inside your HTML, use the $results array 
    // rather than the MySQL resource
    foreach ($results as $row)
    {
      echo $row['name'];
    }
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I am trying to do, thanks. I have tried your code though and I get a parse error - unexpected '{' after line 2. What is 'mysql_fetch_assoc' btw, am I not to use 'mysql_fetch_array'?

Comment: @user1501500 Sorry, missing a closing `)`, fixed above.

Comment: @user1501500 `mysql_fetch_array()` returns both numeric column numbers and column names as keys while `mysql_fetch_assoc()` returns only column names as keys. Since you are only using the column name `name`, you don't need the numeric indices, and `mysql_fetch_assoc()` is therefore a tiny bit more efficient.

Comment: Great! Thanks, Michael. I am actually going to use more than the one iteration, 'name' was just for test purposes, so I took out ['name'] from $row['name'] and it returned everything. Also for the purposes of others who might want to use this code there is a space between the $i in the for statement. Cheers, gavin

Comment: This is the first time I've posted a query on stackoverflow and you getting back to me (and others) straight away has made my afternoon. Thanks!

Comment: @user1501500 Welcome to Stack Overflow.  For all but the most esoteric questions, you can expect at least one answer within 2-3 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I don't understand well but you should try this :

```
$i=1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) && $i <= 20) {
    echo "<div class=\"Box ".$i."\">";
    echo $i;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row['name'];
    echo "</div>";
    $i++;
}
```

Because in your code, you do your "mysql loop" inside the first loop.

Comment: This is the most efficient way +1

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this,

```
$i=1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<div class=\"Box ".$i."\">";
    echo $i;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row['name'];
    echo "</div>";
    $i++;

}
```

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately this doesn't work either. I've had this result before - it creates a "Box" div for every row in my table, with the row data in each Box. I need to create 20 (for example) divs and populate each one with all table data (or at least check all table data with an if)

Comment: I think I need two loops - one to iterate the array and another outside of that to repeat that iteration x amount of times. Thanks though

Comment: I see Michael had submitted something which can help you better, try it.

Answer (score 0):

Once mysql_fetch_array($result) is given, $result cannot be used again for fetch. So it won't work in a loop. Better store the result in an array and use it wherever needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql_data_seek to reset to pointer of the result, if you want to while through them all again, do:

```
mysql_data_seek ( $result, 0 );
```